# Issue with copying and applying rotation values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am copying rotation values of my model into a Vector3 and then I re-apply it back to my model, the rotation values changes completely.

For example, my Model has rotation as `(-180, 0, 0)`. I then copy it to a Vector3, the model's rotation does not get copied. It is shown as `(0, 0, 0)`. After that I finally add back the rotation to my model and the rotation of my model changes to `(0, 180, 0)`. What is wrong with it?

```
public GameObject myModel;
public Vector3 rotationValues_;

public void Start(){
   rotationValues_ = myModel.transform.eulerAngles;
}

public void ResetValue(){
   myModel.transform.eulerAngles = rotationValues_;
}
```

Comment: Nothing ^^ See [`Quaternion.eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-eulerAngles.html) `When you read the .eulerAngles property, Unity converts the Quaternion's internal representation of the rotation to Euler angles. Because, there is more than one way to represent any given rotation using Euler angles, the values you read back out may be quite different from the values you assigned.`

Comment: Also note that the one displayed in the Editor is actually the `localRotation` ... if your model has a parent object that is also rotated the global rotation eulers you are storing and assigning might be again quite different from what you would expect

Comment: What speaks against rather storing the actual `transform.rotation` in a `Quaternion` ?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. The model does have a parent but that is fixed in world position with all values as Zero. Can you please post an answer of how to fix this problem?

Comment: I tried with Quaternion.eulerAngles and I am still facing the  same problem.

Comment: Of course it is the same problem because it is exactly the same thing ^^ Do not use Euler at all .. simply store the rotation as `Quaternion`

Comment: I am saving it as quaternion as ```Quaternion rot = myModel.transform.localRotation``` but when I went to re-apply them as ```myModel.transform.localRotation = rot```, the same thing happened.

Comment: But does the rotation match or not? As said for the euler values displayed in the Inspector there are multiple possible representations of the same quaternion rotation value ... If the rotation does not match something else in your code is wrong

Comment: No unfortunately it does not match. I have tried every solution but it still does not work.

Comment: Consider reading documentation before posting a question. Unity has an article specific to such a fundamental topic. Unity is based on Quaternion but has some Euler angle APIs. https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/Manual/QuaternionAndEulerRotationsInUnity.html

Answer (score 0):

Quaternions have 4 axis instead of 3, the simple solution would be store the rotation data as a `Quaternion` class instead of a `Vector3`.

```
public GameObject myModel;
public Quaternion rotationValues_;

public void Start(){
   rotationValues_ = myModel.transform.rotation;
}

public void ResetValue(){
   myModel.transform.rotation = rotationValues_;
}
```

If you really need to store these values then use:

```
myModel.transform.rotation.eulerAngles
```